# Spring Boot Solr configuration for multiple Instances

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, solr

Several times ago I had the task of using two independent Apache Solr instances in the same application. I tried to find some information, but to no avail. This article is about how to configure access to several independent Apache Solr and access them through different repositories using Spring Data.

**Solr config**

You need to have an independent config for each Solr. For example:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = {"com.project.repository.first"},
            solrClientRef = "firstSolrClient",
            solrTemplateRef = "firstSolrTemplate")
    public class FirstSolrConfig {

        @Value("${solr.first.url}")
        private String solrHost;

        @Bean
        public SolrClient solrClient() {
            return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrHost).build();
        }

        @Bean("firstSolrTemplate")
        public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
            return new SolrTemplate(this::solrClient);
        }

    }
```

-

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = {"com.project.repository.second"},
        solrClientRef = "secondSolrClient",
        solrTemplateRef = "secondSolrTemplate")
public class SecondSolrConfig {

    @Value("${solr.second.url}")
    private String solrHost;

    @Bean("secondSolrClient")
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrHost).build();
    }

    @Bean("secondSolrTemplate")
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
        return new SolrTemplate(this::solrClient);
    }

}
```

SolrClient Bean from first config **MUST** have "solrClient" name! Otherwise, you will not be able to raise the Spring Context.
You need to put your repositories in different packages.

It is only working way I found for this case.

Comment: Did this work in the different packages?

Answer (score 1):

Today i ran into the same issue. It looks like `solrClientRef = "secondSolrClient"` does not work anymore. Without going into the details i can tell, that this feature got remove or probably moved with this [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/commit/68464c9401dcfc5bfb34fe6c2f92f621f5df38b8#diff-65c6bce9b805d152d20410018df5e63d). For now i was not able to come up with another solution, so i stick to

> at least one Bean named `solrClient` has to exist

Here is some code, illustrating my working solution:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(solrTemplateRef = "firstSolrTemplate")
@EntityScan
@ComponentScan
public class FirstSolrConfiguration {

    @Bean("firstSolrClient")
    public SolrClient firstSolrClient(@Qualifier("firstSolrCredentialsProvider") final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
        //
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "solrClient")
    public SolrClient solrClient(@Qualifier("firstSolrCredentialsProvider") final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
        //
    }

    @Bean("firstSolrTemplate")
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() {
        //
    }

}
```

I also have a second configuration for my second connection.